# Selecting com ports for ESP32 Dev on arduino ide

Tags: serial-port, port, arduino-ide, esp32

So if you open the arduino ide and select tools > port > com(?) I usually have an option of 3 to 4 coms to select. I can not for the life of me remember how I fixed this problem last time so that in my tools > port options I can select the correct com to plug in the USB in order to upload a program. As of now my port option only shows COM10 but that is not the right one and I have 3 different USB ports, 2 on the left, 1 on the right and these are usually 3, 4, and 9.

Comment: what type of SO it being used?

Comment: windows 10. i figured out that it was a problem with my drivers and directly after that a windows update popped it's pretty face in the mix. after those few updates were applied then it all works smoothly thanks :)